# Count Cells By Colour with COUNTIF

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following macro CountCellsByColor (ORIGNAL BELOW) however I want to amend it so that it counts cells by color AND the specific text of the cell.

eg: The range has 5 different names all colored a different colour. I want the macro to only count the cells with the same name and color as the reference cell. ie Number of "Fred" 'yellow'cells

ORIGINAL FORMULA BELOW:

```
Function CountCellsByColor(rData As Range, cellRefColor As Range) As Long
    Dim indRefColor As Long
    Dim cellCurrent As Range
    Dim cntRes As Long

    Application.Volatile
    cntRes = 0
    indRefColor = cellRefColor.Cells(1, 1).Interior.Color
    For Each cellCurrent In rData
        If indRefColor = cellCurrent.Interior.Color Then
            cntRes = cntRes + 1
        End If
    Next cellCurrent

    CountCellsByColor = cntRes
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, your original comment worked 
ie - If indRefColor = cellCurrent.Interior.Color And cellCurrent.Value = searchtext Then - I just didnt enter it write initially. Thank you muchly for your assistance. Really appreciate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should suffice to change

```
If indRefColor = cellCurrent.Interior.Color Then
```

to

```
If (indRefColor = cellCurrent.Interior.Color) AND (cellRefColor.cells(1,1).value=cellCurrent.value) Then
```

Answer (score -1):

hope you are looking for this.

```
Function CountCellsByColor(rData As Range, cellRefColor As Range, searchtext As String) As Long
    Dim indRefColor As Long
    Dim cellCurrent As Range
    Dim cntRes As Long
    Application.Volatile
    cntRes = 0
    indRefColor = cellRefColor.Cells(1, 1).Interior.Color
    For Each cellCurrent In rData
        If indRefColor = cellCurrent.Interior.Color And cellCurrent.Value = searchtext Then
            cntRes = cntRes + 1
        End If
    Next cellCurrent
    CountCellsByColor = cntRes
End Function
```

**Working Sample**

[image]